# Some more multitasking java issues

Tags: java, multithreading, multitasking

I had a task to write simple game simulating two players picking up 1-3 matches one after another until the pile is gone. I managed to do it for computer choosing random value of matches but now I'd like to go further and allow humans to play the game. Here's what I already have : http://paste.pocoo.org/show/200660/

Class Player is a computer player, and PlayerMan should be human being. Problem is, that thread of PlayerMan should wait until proper value of matches is given but I cannot make it work this way. When I type the values it sometimes catches them and decrease amount of matches but that's not exactly what I was up to :) Logics is : I check the value of current player. If it corresponds to this of the thread currently active I use scanner to catch the amount of matches. Else I wait one second (I know it's kinda harsh solution, but I have no other idea how to do it).
Class Shared keeps the value of current player, and also amount of matches.

By the way, is there any way I can make Player and Shared attributes private instead of public and still make the code work ?

CONSOLE and INPUT-DIALOG is just for choosing way of inserting values.

```
class PlayerMan extends Player{

    static final int CONSOLE=0;
    static final int INPUT_DIALOG=1;
    private int input;

    public PlayerMan(String name, Shared data, int c){
    super(name, data);
    input = c;
    }

@Override
    public void run(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 0;

        System.out.println("Matches on table: "+data.matchesAmount);
        System.out.println("which: "+data.which);
        System.out.println("number: "+number);

        while(data.matchesAmount != 0){
            if(number == data.which){

                System.out.println("Choose amount of matches (from 1 to 3): ");
                n = scanner.nextInt();

                if(data.matchesAmount == 1){
                    System.out.println("There's only 1 match left !");
                    while(n != 1){
                        n = scanner.nextInt();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    do{
                        n = scanner.nextInt();
                    }
                    while(n <= 1 && n >= 3);
                }

                data.matchesAmount = data.matchesAmount - n;
                System.out.println("                          "+
                        name+" takes "+n+" matches.");
                if(number != 0){
                    data.which = 0;
                }
                else{
                    data.which = 1;
                }
            }
            else{
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch(InterruptedException exc) {
                    System.out.println("End of thread.");
                    return;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Matches on table: "+data.matchesAmount);
        }
        if(data.matchesAmount == 0){
            System.out.println("Winner is player: "+name);
            stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should synchronize with reader/writer locks. **EDIT**: On a second thought, perhaps a simple condition should be enough. You could use something like this:

```
private Lock playerLock = new ReentrantLock();
private Condition[] playerConditions = { playerLock.newCondition(), playerLock.newCondition() };

// Later on:
while (data.matchesAmount != 0) {
  while (number != data.which) {
    playerConditions[number].await();
  }
  // do work here

  // now release the other player -- this assumes there are only 2
  data.which = 1 - number;
  playerConditions[1 - number].signalAll();
}
```

The only problem here is that you may block both threads waiting for their conditions if `data.which` is not properly initialized when they get here. You should make sure it is initialized *before* starting their threads.

Comment: I've just found something about this, also wait() method. So should I add method for writing number of matches synchronize it and insert into run()?

Comment: @owca Basically, any data that is read or written by more than one thread should be synchronized. You may use the `synchronized` keyword around methods that do so, you may use `synchronized (object) { ... }` inside a method, you may use locks, or you may use conditions (shown in the updated answer). Never try to just use a variable, because data is not guaranteed to be consistent between threads without a lock of some kind.